# Get image from Grid view

Tags: android

Hi I have an Activity(Activity_1) which calls another Activity(Activity_2) using activity for result. In Activity_2 I have a grid view which shows some images. I want to show the selected image from grid view to the Image view in Activity_1. Can anyone tell me how to send the image details in grid view to the first activity.

Note the images are in my drawable folder.

Thanks,

Regards, Sniper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your images are in your `drawable` folder, then you can simply return the ID of the image to the calling activity.  In the `onFinish` of your second activity, just call `setResult(R.drawable.selected_image)` - then in your first activity, once you get that result, just use `setDrawableResource(received_result)` on your ImageView.

Comment: how to find the drawable of selected image. Which listener i have to use and where to use.

Comment: @Sniper: How is your grid set up?  You'll probably need to set its Adapter, inside the adapter's `getView` display the corresponding image and in the Adapter's `getItemId` method return the R.drawable.image_id of the image being displayed.  Then set OnItemClickListener to your grid and it its `onClick` event get the ID of the clicked item in the grid, put it into a member variable and call `finish` on your activity.  Finally, in the activity's `onFinish` call `setResult` with the value of this member variable.

Answer (score 1):

You start your second activity for a result;
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)

You set a listener on each item and set the result of the clicked item and pass it back to activity 1

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

You can override the result callback and get the image they picked in activity 2

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //TODO handle here. 
}
```